# Windows Code-Signing Over Existing Code Sign?

Tags: windows, exe, code-signing

I'm new to Windows code-signing. If an EXE is already code-signed, from a command line, can we code sign again with another EV cert (different company)? Or, do I need the freshly unsigned EXE again to code sign it? The developers that we hired have left. The source won't compile. All we have is the EXE.

Comment: I think you can sign it again - but try it and see.  OTOH, if you don't have compilable source and the developers have gone, how confident are you that the EXE hasn't been booby trapped?

Comment: Not confident. But will only do this as a placeholder while another contractor team rebuilds from scratch. I loathed their source, anyway, when I reviewed it.